# Linux CLI Timestamp Parsing

Tags: linux, parsing, timestamp, wget

Using AWS Linux.
I have the following command line statement:

```
wget  --output-document=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M.%3N`.txt http://foo/foo.txt
```

My question is:
Will the date command be parsed on command parse or when the file is written?
E.g. if I execute the command at exactly 9AM, will the timestamp on the file be exactly 9AM, 9AM plus the time it took to parse the command or 9AM plus the time it took to receive the file?

Thanks
Hsnopi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backticks get expanded by the shell.
`wget` will get the expanded string. The backticked command will run before `wget`.

If you run the command at exactly 9AM, the timestamp will be 9AM + the time it took to spawn `date` and do the things it does before it retrieves the time from the system (this may or may not include parsing the output format string). The time it'll take to retrieve the file won't play a role because that'll happen after the date command ran.